# How to see action of a webpage in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, action, erb

Is there a field or method I can lookup within an `.html.erb` file that will tell me the current action used to render the page? This code would be in a partial. I'm looking for something like this:

```
<% if @action == :new %>
  this is new
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have `action_name` and `controller_name` for this purpose.

**But note**: the result is a string, not a symbol.

See the [explanation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
<% if params[:action] ==  "new" %>
  # do something here
<% end %>
```